sed command changing while robot tests are runs
I am running a sed command within robot test:
${stdout01}=   Run   echo ${stdout0} | sed "s/\'/\"/g"

It is not running properly and giving me error:
 /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Logs of variable stdout01 are showing the following:
Running command 'echo "{'config': {'adminPassword': 'admin', 'affinity': {}, 'env': {'LDAP_BACKEND': 'hdb', 'LDAP_DOMAIN': 'example.org', 'LDAP_ORGANISATION': 'Example Inc.', 'LDAP_REMOVE_CONFIG_AFTER_SETUP': 'true', 'LDAP_TLS': 'true', 'LDAP_TLS_ENFORCE': 'false'}, 'existingSecret': '', 'extraLabels': {}, 'image': {'pullPolicy': 'IfNotPresent', 'repository': 'osixia/openldap', 'tag': '1.2.4'}, 'initResources': {}, 'kdu_reset_values': 'True', 'logLevel': 'info', 'nodeSelector': {}, 'persistence': {'accessMode': 'ReadWriteOnce', 'enabled': False, 'size': '8Gi'}, 'podAnnotations': {}, 'replicaCount': 3, 'resources': {}, 'service': {'annotations': {}, 'externalIPs': [], 'ldapPort': 389, 'loadBalancerIP': '', 'loadBalancerSourceRanges': [], 'sslLdapPort': 636}, 'sessionAffinity': 'None', 'strategy': {}, 'test': {'enabled': False, 'image': {'repository': 'dduportal/bats', 'tag': '0.4.0'}}, 'tls': {'CA': {'enabled': False, 'secret': ''}, 'enabled': False, 'secret': ''}, 'tolerations': [], 'type': 'NodePort'}, 'info': {'deleted': '', 'description': 'Upgrade complete', 'first_deployed': '2024-07-06T22:35:31.029710808Z', 'last_deployed': '2024-07-06T22:36:55.592819454Z', 'status': 'deployed'}, 'manifest': [{'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Secret', 'metadata': {'name': 'stable-openldap-0031883975', 'labels': {'app': 'openldap', 'chart': 'openldap-1.2.7', 'release': 'stable-openldap-0031883975', 'heritage': 'Helm'}}, 'type': 'Opaque', 'data': {'LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD': 'YWRtaW4=', 'LDAP_CONFIG_PASSWORD': 'R3pIem5laGdOTERvRThTRjkzMFhRa25lb2dnVGlXMUw='}}, {'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'ConfigMap', 'metadata': {'name': 'stable-openldap-0031883975-env', 'labels': {'app': 'openldap', 'chart': 'openldap-1.2.7', 'release': 'stable-openldap-0031883975', 'heritage': 'Helm'}}, 'data': {'LDAP_BACKEND': 'hdb', 'LDAP_DOMAIN': 'example.org', 'LDAP_ORGANISATION': 'Example Inc.', 'LDAP_REMOVE_CONFIG_AFTER_SETUP': 'true', 'LDAP_TLS': 'true', 'LDAP_TLS_ENFORCE': 'false'}}, {'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Service', 'metadata': {'name': 'stable-openldap-0031883975', 'labels': {'app': 'openldap', 'chart': 'openldap-1.2.7', 'release': 'stable-openldap-0031883975', 'heritage': 'Helm'}}, 'spec': {'ports': [{'name': 'ldap-port', 'protocol': 'TCP', 'port': 389, 'targetPort': 'ldap-port'}, {'name': 'ssl-ldap-port', 'protocol': 'TCP', 'port': 636, 'targetPort': 'ssl-ldap-port'}], 'selector': {'app': 'openldap', 'release': 'stable-openldap-0031883975'}, 'type': 'ClusterIP'}}, {'apiVersion': 'apps/v1', 'kind': 'Deployment', 'metadata': {'name': 'stable-openldap-0031883975', 'labels': {'app': 'openldap', 'chart': 'openldap-1.2.7', 'release': 'stable-openldap-0031883975', 'heritage': 'Helm'}}, 'spec': {'replicas': 3, 'selector': {'matchLabels': {'app': 'openldap', 'release': 'stable-openldap-0031883975'}}, 'template': {'metadata': {'annotations': {'checksum/configmap-env': 'a03fdce5acf782098d8f0070464c97b880845af501e7d3a2878c7c71727890f4'}, 'labels': {'app': 'openldap', 'release': 'stable-openldap-0031883975'}}, 'spec': {'containers': [{'name': 'openldap', 'image': 'osixia/openldap:1.2.4', 'imagePullPolicy': 'IfNotPresent', 'args': ['-l', 'info'], 'ports': [{'name': 'ldap-port', 'containerPort': 389}, {'name': 'ssl-ldap-port', 'containerPort': 636}], 'envFrom': [{'configMapRef': {'name': 'stable-openldap-0031883975-env'}}, {'secretRef': {'name': 'stable-openldap-0031883975'}}], 'volumeMounts': [{'name': 'data', 'mountPath': '/var/lib/ldap', 'subPath': 'data'}, {'name': 'data', 'mountPath': '/etc/ldap/slapd.d', 'subPath': 'config-data'}], 'env': None, 'livenessProbe': {'tcpSocket': {'port': 'ldap-port'}, 'initialDelaySeconds': 20, 'periodSeconds': 10, 'failureThreshold': 10}, 'readinessProbe': {'tcpSocket': {'port': 'ldap-port'}, 'initialDelaySeconds': 20, 'periodSeconds': 10, 'failureThreshold': 10}, 'resources': {}}], 'volumes': [{'name': 'certs', 'emptyDir': {'medium': 'Memory'}}, {'name': 'data', 'emptyDir': {}}]}}}}, None], 'name': 'stable-openldap-0031883975', 'namespace': 'fd4f39a0-ca81-4532-9a5a-16cd491e621d', 'version': 2}" | sed 's/'/"/g' 2>&1'.

which doesnt run well on the terminal. Notice the change in sed command in the Logs. I am baffled how the sed command is getting changed and please advise if I am doing something wrong here.

try sed "s/'/\\"/g" or sed s/\\'/\\"/g

@jhnc or sed -e 's/\o47/*/'g or sed 's/\o47/\o42/g' or even tr \' \" ...

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I'm assuming the problem is that robot is consuming one level of escaping: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#escaping

The robot test framework uses the \ as escape character. Therefore the shell actually sees:
sed "s/'/"/g"

which is an unterminated quoted string.
You need to escape the \ in robot test in order to get a \ to the shell:
${stdout01}=   Run   echo ${stdout0} | sed "s/\\'/\\"/g"


Just to highlight the wording on this answer; Behaviour of  "escape characters" is not unique to Robot Framework - its pretty much a standard in every  programming language.
